# Tensorflow, use import_graph_def() to load model error

Tags: tensorflow

I attempt to read an RNN network through `import_graph_def()` and do inference.
But I cannot use `tf.trainable_variables()` to get any variables.

In the following code, `tf.trainable_variables()` returns [] (a list with nothing)
Also, when I use `saver = tf.train.Saver()`, tensorflow reports "no variables to save"

```
def eval_on_test(graph_path):
batch_size = 80
train_begin = 0
train_end = 3000
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    with open(graph_path, 'rb') as f:
        tf_graph = tf.GraphDef()
        print("Loading graph_def from {}".format(graph_path))
        tf_graph.ParseFromString(f.read())

        return_elements = tf.import_graph_def(tf_graph, name="", return_elements=['input_x:0', 'output_y:0', 'pred:0', 'loss:0'])
        X = return_elements[0]
        Y = return_elements[1]
        pred = return_elements[2]
        loss = return_elements[3]

    tf_config = tf.ConfigProto()
    tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

    print("graph loaded, start testing")
    with tf.Session(config=tf_config) as sess:

        init_op = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('init')
        sess.run(init_op)
        print(tf.trainable_variables())
        batch_index,train_x,train_y=get_train_data(batch_size,time_step,train_begin,train_end)
        for batch in range(len(batch_index)-1):
            loss_ = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:train_x[batch_index[batch]:batch_index[batch+1]],Y:train_y[batch_index[batch]:batch_index[batch+1]]})
            print(batch, loss_)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import_graph_def` will only restore graph but will not restore collections such as `GLOBAL_VARIABLES`, that's why `Saver` can't find any variables in graph, to solve this, you can try `tf.train.import_meta_graph` which will also restore all collections.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That solves my question. I was trying to save and restore graph with graphdef, that post solve the problem, https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/